# Get a number from a different strings

Tags: python

I have big amount of strings. They have a number inside of them. My task is to get all numbers and save to a list.

---

For example:

Input - `['ad21ssda', 'sf9sdsfqw', '098jafad', 'adad2']`

Output - `[21, 9, 98, 2]`

Comment: Did you try anything ? If you have a problem with your code, please explain what it is, and we will be happy to help, but asking us to code for you is not welcome here. Thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

inputs = ['ad21ssda', 'sf9sdsfqw', '098jafad', 'adad2']
result = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+", ' '.join(inputs))]
print(result)
# [21, 9, 98, 2]
```

Comment: too complicated

Comment: @A.Doe This is how you're supposed to use Python. Not complicated if you're understand it.

Answer (score 0):

With simple loops:

```
input = ['ad21ssda', 'sf9sdsfqw', '098jafad', 'adad2']
output = []
for string in input:
    output_element = ''
    for character in string:
        if character.isnumeric():
            output_element = output_element + character
    if output_element != '':
        output.append(int(output_element))
print(output)

>>> [21, 9, 98, 2]
```

I guess regular expressions are the preferred solution, but I'm not that familiar with it and would solve it this way.